# Executing Javascript when a New Post is Published

Tags: plugins, javascript

I thought it was simple, but I can’t do it. I’ve been totally stuck for five days

I want to be able to trigger the Javascript console.log() function when a new post is published

```php
function display_console_log() {
    echo "
        <script>
            console.log('New post published')
        </script>
    ";
}
add_action('auto-draft_to_publish', 'display_console_log');
```

I don’t understand what’s wrong with this code

Thank you in advance to those who will help me

Comment: Is this before a post get published or after?

Comment: If I understand the meaning of 'auto-draft_to_publish', the console.log() function should be triggered after the post is published

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code depends on the post being in an `auto-draft` state immediately before publication, which isn't guaranteed. For a more generic option, try using the [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) hook:

```
function display_console_log( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // Only runs if the post is transitioning from a not-published state
    // to the `publish` state.
    if ( 'publish' !== $old_status && 'publish' === $new_status ) {
        echo "
            <script>
                console.log('New post published')
            </script>
        ";
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'display_console_log', 10, 3 );
```

(Also, tangentially related, it's not in keeping with the WordPress Way to inject JavaScript code directly; I recommend reading up on how and why to use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).)

Comment: So I used the wrong action hook and my way of executing JavaScript is not the right one. Now I understand why it doesn’t work. I will take some time to understand  transition_post_status and wp_enqueue_script(). Thank you